# log4net logging to SQL Server database

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I'm using log4net to log errors to a SQL Server database. It works ok but there is one problem. The log table in the database contains a column called `Exception` this never gets populated but all the other columns do. My config is setup ok, can anyone tell me why this should be happening ?

Here's the commandtext section in my `web.config` file

```
commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date], [Thread], [Level], [Logger],[Message], [Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
```

Comment: How are your exceptions been logged? You need to make sure you are using the `void Error(Object message,Exception exception)` method.

Comment: this._log.ErrorFormat(ex.Message);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the error column, you need to give the exception as argument to the log.Error method:

```
try{
  throw new Exception();
catch (Exception ex){
  _log.Error("error msg", ex);
}
```

See the [ILog interface](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_ILog.htm)

> Error(Object)  Logs a message object with the Error level.
>
> Error(Object, Exception)   **Log a message object with the Error
> level including the stack trace of the Exception passed as a
> parameter.**
>
> ErrorFormat(String, Object)    Logs a formatted
> message string with the Error level.
>
> ErrorFormat(String,Object[])   Logs a formatted message string
> with the Error level.
>
> ErrorFormat(IFormatProvider,
> String,Object[])   Logs a formatted message string with the Error
> level.
>
> ErrorFormat(String, Object, Object)    Logs a
> formatted message string with the Error level.
>
> ErrorFormat(String, Object, Object, Object)     Logs a formatted
> message string with the Error level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct overload, ie

```
void Error(Object message,Exception exception)
```

As you are using `this._log.ErrorFormat(ex.Message)`, you are not passing the exception, but just the message as a string to log4net.